# Enabling X11 forwarding permanently

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I have a PHP program and in order to run a batch file, I have typed:

```
$> xhost +
$> ssh username@hostname -X
$> ssh username@hostname -Y
```

And, it works fine. But, my problem is that when I restart my computer or download something, I have to do this all over again.

Is there a way to enable X11 forwarding permanently on a pc? I have to mention that X11 forwarding is yes in configuration file, but I have to type the mentioned commands for my GUI to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need (and don't want) `xhost +`.

Just update (or create) your `.ssh/config` file with the following for the equivalent of `-X`:

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
```

Or for the equivalent of `-Y`:

```
Host *
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

This will affect your connections to *all* hosts.  You can of course use something other than `*` to limit these configurations changes to particular hosts/domains/etc.

Comment: OK Thank you, I am going to update the .ssh/config file, but why "You don't need (and don't want) xhost +." ?

Comment: You don't want it because that permits anyone, on any host anywhere, to access your X display (where "access" means "able to grab anything on your screen, your keystrokes, etc).  It's not necessary because `ssh` manages X display authentication for you, using [MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Security/) authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.ssh/config have something like this:

```
Host server1
   HostName server1
   ForwardX11 yes
   User username
```