# Enabling X11 forwarding permanently in OSX Sierra

Tags: ssh, x11, osx

The problem I have is that

```
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

does not appear to work.  I have a config file set up to allow connection to my remote host.  This is what it looks like (edited to remove potentially sensitive information):

```
Host NNN
    HostName XXX.YYY.COM
    User UUUUU
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/NNN
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

When I log in using **ssh -X NNN** or **ssh -Y NNN** forwarding works just fine.  When I log in using **ssh NNN** I get a display error.

I'm using OSX 10.12.6.  Is this a new problem?  A reboot did not change the behavior.

Please note that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225166/enabling-x11-forwarding-permanently) is very similar, but the answer does not work and it is for ubuntu and not OSX, it is therefore not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on both X11, and Trusted X11:

```
Host ...
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
```